# Why Can't I add List<T> is it due to Bark?

Tags: c#, generics

Working on a coding problem, I need to use a generic List instead of arrays for this one, but having trouble figuring out why it won't allow me to add generic List
I have an abstract base class, which my other classes inherit from.

```
public abstract class Pet
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Pet(string name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: nom nom nom", Name));
    }
}

public class Dog: Pet
{
    public Dog(string name):base(name)
    {

    }

    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: bark", Name));
    }
}
```

And finally I have a program.cs file which contains the following.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Dog lassie = new Dog("Lassie");
    Dog benji = new Dog("Benji");
    Dog oddie = new Dog("Oddie");

    Cat garfield = new Cat("Garfield");
    Cat tony = new Cat("Tony");
    Cat felix = new Cat("Felix");

    Dog[] dogs = { lassie, benji, oddie };
    List<string> dogList = new List<string>();
    dogList.Add("Lassie");
    dogList.Add("Benji");
    dogList.Add("Oddie");

    List<string> catList = new List<string>();
    catList.Add("Garfield");
    catList.Add("Tony");
    catList.Add("Felix");

    Cat[] cats = { garfield, tony, felix };
    Pet[] pets = { garfield, lassie, tony, benji, oddie, felix };

    Bark(dogList);
    Meow(cats);
    Feed(pets);

    Call(pets);

    ListCatsThenDogsInAlphabeticalOrder(pets);

    Console.WriteLine("Done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static void MakeAList(Dog[] dogs)
{
    List<string> dogList = new List<string>();
    for (int i=0;i < dogs.Length; i++)
    {
        dogList.Add(dogs[i]);

    }
}

private static void Bark(Dog[] dogs)
{
    foreach (Dog dog in dogs)
        dog.Bark();
}

private static void Meow(Cat[] cats)
{
    foreach (Cat cat in cats)
        cat.Meow();
}

private static void Feed(Pet[] animals)
{
    foreach (Pet animal in animals)
        animal.Eat();
}

/// <summary>
///   Calls a pet.  The pet should respond by barking or meowing as appropriate.
/// </summary>
/// 
/// <param name="pets">
///   A list of pets.  Not null and contains no nulls.
/// </param>

private static void Call(Pet[] pets)
{
    foreach (Cat cat in pets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Come here " + cat.Name);
        cat.Meow();
    }

    foreach (Dog dog in pets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Come here " + dog.Name);
        dog.Bark();
    }
}

private static void ListCatsThenDogsInAlphabeticalOrder(Pet[] pets)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nPets");
    Console.WriteLine("----------");

    // Use a linq expression or extension methods to sort the pets first by type (cats first, dogs second),
    // and then by alphabetically by their names.  Print the sorted list.

    foreach (Pet pet in pets)

        Console.WriteLine(pet.Name);

    Console.WriteLine("----------");
}
```

Problem I am having is that it doesn't seem to like my attempt to make a `List<string> dogList` due to the bark method, not sure how to fix it. I'm quite stuck on how to make it work, the call to `Bark(dogList)` fails with:

> Argument1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List
>   to Problem4.Dog[]

Comment: You've posted a lot of code here. Could you reduce it to a *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem? Also, show the *exact* error and where it occurs rather than "it doesn't seem to like". (If you could reformat the code to be more readable too, that would be great. The second section isn't too bad, but the Pet class indentation is all over the place.)

Comment: A `List<T>` is not the same as `T[]`.  It can be converted to an array via `ToArray()` (but the array will be separate, changes to the array won't affect the list and vice versa).  And both `List<T>` and `T[]` can be passed to a method that expects `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`.  Furthermore, a `List<string>` is not the same as a `List<Dog>` -- a `string` doesn't know how to bark.

Comment: check updated answer that will resolve your issue

Comment: Could you share the line when is crashing? It might help or a print screen of the exception. Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This also problem with your code , you are creating list of string and passing string list in the method which is expecting list of `Pets` type defined by you.

```
   List<string> dogList = new List<string>();
    dogList.Add("Lassie");
    dogList.Add("Benji");
    dogList.Add("Oddie");
    //Bark(dogList);this is not going to work as you are passing string array
```

it should be

```
   List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>();
    dogList.Add(new Dog("Lassie"));
    dogList.Add(new Dog("Benji"));
    dogList.Add(new Dog("Oddie"));
    Bark(dogList);

   private static void Bark(IEnumerable<Dog> dogs)
   {
     foreach (Dog dog in dogs)
        dog.Bark();
   }
```

same goes for catlist also and it will work.

---

best way to resolve it is make it as `IEnumerable<T>`, so code will be

User `IEnumerable` this will handle both `Array and List`

```
    static void Call(IEnumerable<Pet> pets)
    {

    }
```

Note: I suggested `IEnumerable` as you are using `foreach` there is no access to element by `Index`, if you want `Index` base access then make use of `IList`

---

To support bark method for both `cat` and `dog`, make new interface `IBark` and implement it as given below and also change bark method as given below

```
   interface IBark { void Bark(); }
   public class Dog:Pet,IBark {
     public Dog(string name):base(name)
     {}
     public void Bark()
     {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: bark", Name));
     }
   }
   //do same changes with cat
```

so in main class it will be like

```
   static void Call(IEnumerable<IBark> pets)
   {
    foreach (IBark pet in pets)
        pet.Bark();
   }
```

---

Comment: ListCatsThenDogsInAlphabeticalOrder(list); gives me Argument1: cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<Problem4.Pet> to Problem4.Pet (problem4 is the namespace)

Comment: @webdev8183 - updated my answer you need to pass list of dog or cat not list of string ...

Comment: *`//will work as dog is subtype of pet`* - why is this even necessary?

Comment: @Rafalon - i missed that to remove in my edits ..thanks for pointing it out remove that line now

Comment: Thanks Pranay, I think I am almost there but i am getting a system invalid cast exception unable to cast object of type problem4.dog to type problem4 cat, in the call(petList) function

Comment: @webdev8183 - you have to change singlare of call like this    private `static void Call(IEnumerable<Pet> pets)`

Comment: I have done that the problem is that Pet does not know about meow or bark, since those methods are in the cat and dog class not in the base class,  how would i fix that? It has me a bit stuck

Comment: Maybe add a virtual `Speak()` method to your `Pet` and override it in `Cat` to call `Meow()` and in `Dog` to call `Bark()`?

Comment: @Rafalon - interface will do , there is no need to affect parent class

Comment: @webdev8183 - check my updaed , you need to create interface to support that part

Comment: @PranayRana I don't understand, are `Cat`s supposed to implement `IBark`?

Comment: @Rafalon - if there is need of cat need to be bark then yes , otherwise there is no need ...I created interface because there might be some animal that dont bark , then you dont need to implement that interface for them

Comment: I get what you are saying but I am still not sure how to fix it, rafalon you are right I want to have a bark and a meow , but I am not sure how to add them would it be better to add an ISpeak in the base class and then provide a bark for dog and a meow for cat? just not sure how that should look/work but it is what I want to do

Comment: the cat has a meow and the dog has a bark already but since I am passing in the pet, it doesn't know about these methods

Comment: @webdev8183 - you are trying to cast prent to child that is not possible in C#, you need to do other way like reflection for doing it

Comment: I figured it out, I created an public abstract method speak and override it for each child class.

Comment: now I am working on getting the Linq Query to sort Cats, then dogs

Comment: I need to compose a linq query that will sort the pets first by type(cats first, dogs second, then alphabetically by their names, and print the sorted list.

Comment: @webdev8183 - for doing that you need to have `Type Enum`  and you need that Type of enum property in you pet class , that will do for you

Answer (score 1):

[Cats & Dogs (test it online)](http://tpcg.io/me4wqq)

Classes definition (as per my comment on [Pranay Rana's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49644059/7831383)):

```
public abstract class Pet
{    
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Pet(string name)
    {
        this.Name=name;
    }
    public void Eat()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: nom nom nom", Name));
    }
    public abstract void Speak();
}

public class Dog: Pet
{
    public Dog(string name):base(name){}

    public override void Speak()
    {
        Bark();
    }
    public void Bark()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: bark", Name));
    }
}

public class Cat: Pet
{
    public Cat(string name):base(name){}

    public override void Speak()
    {
        Meow();
    }
    public void Meow()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: meow", Name));
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following to call and list the pets:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Pet> Pets = new List<Pet>();    
        Pets.Add(new Dog("Lassie"));
        Pets.Add(new Cat("Garfield"));
        Pets.Add(new Dog("Benji"));
        Pets.Add(new Cat("Tony"));
        Pets.Add(new Dog("Oddie"));
        Pets.Add(new Cat("Felix"));

        Call(Pets);

        Console.WriteLine();

        ListCatsThenDogs(Pets);
    }

    static void Call(IEnumerable<Pet> Pets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calling all pets...");

        foreach (Pet pet in Pets)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Come here " + pet.Name);
            pet.Speak(); // using the abstract Speak() method
        }
    }

    static void ListCatsThenDogs(IEnumerable<Pet> Pets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Listing cats then dogs in alphabetical order...");

        foreach(Pet pet in Pets
            .OrderBy(p => p.GetType().FullName) // order by type ("Cat" < "Dog")
            .ThenBy(p => p.Name))               // then by name
        {
            Console.WriteLine(pet.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was perfect, I was almost there that Linq syntax gets me every time, I am going through a course on pluralsight to get better at it, I am more used to SQL and Linq just feels backwards, though I know it is closer to how queries actually execute..

Comment: @webdev8183 Glad that helped you :) Feel free to upvote any useful answer, and whenever an answer solves your question, don't forget to mark it as accepted ;)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass a `List<T>` as an array `T[]`.

Use `Bark(dogs)` instead.

However, you could pass an array `T[]` as an `IList<T>`. Most often you would use `IEnumerable<T>` as arguments. You can pass both arrays and lists as `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a couple of errors:

The method **MakeAList** should be as follows:

```
private static List<string> MakeAList(Dog[] dogs)
{
    List<string> dogList = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dogs.Length; i++)
    {
        dogList.Add(dogs[i].Name);
    }
    return dogList;
}
```

You need to set the **name** of the **Dog**, you cannot set an object because if not it should be a ***List of Dogs*** not a ***List of Strings***.

Second you cannot use a **List of Strings** if you need a **List of Dogs**:

```
List<Dog> dogList = new List<Dog>();
dogList.Add(new Dog("Lassie"));
dogList.Add(new Dog("Benji"));
dogList.Add(new Dog("Oddie"));
```

Finally, as a passing a List when you should pass an Array, you can convert with with [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx):

```
Bark(dogList.ToArray());
Meow(cats.ToArray());
Feed(pets.ToArray());
```

Some advice, **do not mix** **Arrays** with **Lists**, this will impact in the performance of your projects.

Comment: What's the point of *making a list* if you don't `return` that list?

Comment: Hi @Rafalon, personally, I just fixed and explained his code and what was he doing wrong with some advice. Why is he not returning anything? Since, I don't know the rest of the core or where he is calling the function I can just theorize based on the name, that's why I didn't go deeper because he could do anything with the method, but thanks for highlighting the point.